# OpenGL fill frustum with quad

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to write an OpenGL/GLSL app that will use GLSL for image processing. I've done some research and come to the conclusion that the right approach is to render to a framebuffer object and then retrieve the image from the gpu. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to set up the frustum and render the quadrilateral so that it fills it properly. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Use a quad (or two triangles) with vertices located at each corner of the Normalized Device Coordinate space: (-1,-1,0) - (1,1,0). Use identity matrices for modelview and projection matrices (or since you're using shaders, simply pass the vertices untransformed through) and this will be the simplest approach imaginable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render with an orthogonal projection matrix.

```
glPushMatrix(GL_WORLDVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2i(0, 0);
glVertex2i(width, 0);
glVertex2i(width, height);
glVertex2i(0, height);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_WORLDVIEW);
glPopMatrix();
```

Width and height are the dimensions of your FBO. Of course they could be both one if you don't need to address special parts of your FBO by drawing quads at pixel positions.